# Can I use "human intervention" in this context? Are there better alternatives?

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

> Applying self-organized Multiagent systems in the industry can lower the necessity of **human intervention**, which can imply a signicant reduction in costs.

Please note that I want to emphasize that the "intervention" is an unregular event, only needed under exceptional circumstances (e.g. fault).

Comment: Thank you. You're completely right. I'll remove that last sentence.

Comment: What about manpower for troubleshooting or simply trouble shooters.

Comment: In my opinion manpower sounds like a solid choice, but it's also a lot more generic than "human intervention", since it doesn't emphasize the unregularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quotation is from *Sources of human productivity* by Robert R. Carkhuff:

> Intervention implies **human intervention** and involves influencing the personal reasons by helping, training or supporting in some way. In turn, the non- intervention methods may involve mechanical interventions...

So taking into account your note "that the "intervention" is an unregular event, only needed under exceptional circumstances (e.g. fault).", I cannot think of another word that would fit better.